# Overloading operator<< template classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio for source code editor, and when I try to compile the below code I got an linker error:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class X<int> &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAV?$X@H@@@Z) referenced in function _main  Zadatak7.19.04.2021 C:\Users\AT95\Desktop\Zadatak7.19.04.2021\Zadatak7.19.04.2021\main.obj  1

What must I do to make this program work correctly?

I want you to look at the definition of the overloading `operator<<` because
that method is causing errors.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class X
{

private:

    int index, capacity;

    T* collection{};
        
public:

    X(const int nmb, const T* array)
    {
        index = 0;

        capacity = nmb;

        collection = new(T[nmb]);

        for (int i = 0; i < nmb; i++)
            collection[index++] = array[i];
    }

    X(const X& other)
    {
        index = other.index;
        capacity = other.capacity;

        collection = new(T[other.capacity]);

        if(other.index < other.capacity)
            for (int i = 0; i < other.index; i++)
                collection[i] = other.collection[i];
    }

    ~X() { delete[] collection; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, X<T>&);

};
        
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, X<T>& other)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < other.index; i++)
        out << i + 1 << ". " << other.collection[i];

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);

    X<int> x(n, array), b(x);

    std::cout << x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a collection of warnings - live - https://godbolt.org/z/3n841MbMj - working my way through them.

Comment: Very useful site, I will give my best to check it out.
Thanks my friend.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @AndrejTrozic regardless of whether that site is used, the hint is to turn on your compiler warnings and read them.  They will tell you where your code looks problematic.

Comment: The site is also helpful because it is good to see what other compilers think of your code. Different compilers give different diagnostics and one compiler might spot a problem that others don't or explain a problem better.  They will generate different output and have different interpretations of [some coding mistakes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and the discrepancies in their output can help find sneaky bugs.

Comment: [Why do I get linker errors when I use template friends?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends)

Answer (score 3):

Your friend dclaration is wrong.

```
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, X<T>&);
```

This is a friend declaration of a non templated `operator<<`.

It should look like this:

```
    template<typename Z>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, X<Z>&);
```

But there is a better way to declare it. Move the function body into the class then you don't need to declare the template part.

```
template <class T>
class X
{

    // STUFF AS BEFORE


    // Friend class definition.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, X& other)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < other.index; i++)
            out << i + 1 << ". " << other.collection[i];

        return out;
    }
}
```

Secondary note. In output operators the object being output is usually declared const (as outputting it should not modify it).

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, X const& other)
                                                        ^^^^^
```

Comment: You may also use `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, X& other) { ... }` when it's inside the class.

Comment: @RSahu Fixed. Getting rusty in my old age.

Comment: Old age has its downsides :) :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to write the `template` keyword at the beginning of the `friend` function, like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class X
{

private:

    int index, capacity;

    T* collection{};

public:

    X(const int nmb, const T* array)
    {
        index = 0;

        capacity = nmb;

        collection = new(T[nmb]);

        for (int i = 0; i < nmb; i++)
            collection[index++] = array[i];
    }

    X(const X& other)
    {
        index = other.index;
        capacity = other.capacity;

        collection = new(T[other.capacity]);

        if(other.index < other.capacity)
            for (int i = 0; i < other.index; i++)
                collection[i] = other.collection[i];
    }

    ~X() { delete[] collection; }

    template<class U> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, X<U>&);

};

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, X<T>& other)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < other.index; i++)
        out << i + 1 << ". " << other.collection[i];

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);

    X<int> x(n, array), b(x);

    std::cout << x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeas, that's it.
Friend of a class is on his own.

Thank you sir !

Comment: That's all right!

Comment: When you add `template` to a friend declaration, you make `operator<<(std::ostream&, X<U>&)` a friend for all `U`s. Formally, this approach works, but it is wrong from the architectural point of view - friendship scope should be as narrow as possible. A better solution is to let a compiler know that `operator<<` is a template with a proper forward declaration, as explained [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends).